# Is it possible to use Doctrine2 batch processing seamlessly with Twig's for tag?

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, iterator, twig

I have certain use cases where I need to show datasets without pagination. In order to save memory I would rather use Doctrine's batch processing features (the query iterator).

I want to know if twig provides any mechanism (writing my own extension is ok) to allow using the [for tag](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/tags/for.html) with an iterator result set just as I would with any other collection.

Then in my extension (or whatever handles the iteration process) I would detach the objects as they are used.

So far, I think my only option is creating a custom for tag, as I don't think twig's for tag handles this.

Comment: Have you tried this? If all you're doing is using the iterable functionality and not modifying the entities, then I think this should work just fine as twig will cause doctrine to hydrate what is needed.

Comment: Also realize that it doesn't matter if you batch query the data in the controller and pass it to the template, or directly in the template, the amount of memory consumed by the operation will be almost exactly the same, the amount of space consumed by the entire data set. The most efficient way to do this would be to query records through ajax and append them to the page.

Comment: I want to avoid hidrating all the objects at the same time, just hidrating the object I need for the current iteration. I don't think the memory consumed would be the same. I think this is what doctrine's iterator is supposed to be good for according to the documentation, unless I totally misunderstood it of course. (See http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/2.0.x/reference/batch-processing.html#iterating-large-results-for-data-processing)

Comment: Moreover, this should even apply to json, having the whole set hidrated at any given moment should not be necessary to generate the right output.

Comment: I agree, I understand that not every object will be hydrated at once. That will use less memory, but there will still be the memory of every element you have hydrated sitting in memory waiting for the page to finish rendering. 1000 objects each hydrating only 1 5kb field will take 5000kb regardless of whether it's done in Twig or in the Controller. However making 10 requests for 100 objects will consume 1000kb per request. This makes the max memory load on your server 1000kb, even though the client is still getting the full 5000kb.

Comment: Oh, ok. So you are talking about chunking the data in multiple requests. That would work. Anyway, I still think this is something that should be possible to do server side. Chunking is a good strategy for several problems, but I think having poorly programed server side software is still not acceptable.

Comment: Maybe I should just ditch the objects and stick to plain old mysql. For some reason whenever there are issues with ORMs the answer is the same.

Comment: Why do this in twig? Build a data set in the controller and then pass that to twig to loop through. Granted you're looping twice, but it's not exponential growth in effort so maybe you're willing to sacrifice the speed.

Comment: That's the point, looping twice implies keeping the whole dataset in memory, and that's what I want to avoid. I finally figured out how to solve it creating a tag specifically for iterating data, thus iterating once and keeping memory clean, I'll post it when it's complete.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Considering that:

1. Doctrine's iterator uses PDO's fetch method (it uses only one object at a time)
2. Doctrine's iterator implements PHP's [Iterator](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.iterator.php) interface

Instead of passing:

```
$query->getResult()
```

to twig you can just pass:

```
$query->iterate()
```

Then in twig instead of doing:

```
{% for item in result %}
     {# do work with item #}
{% endfor %}
```

It should be:

```
{% for item in result %}
     {# doctrine's iterator yields an array for some crazy reason #}
     {% set item = item[0] %} 

     {# do work with item #}

     {# the object should be detached here to avoid staying in the cache #}
{% endfor %}
```

Besides, the loop.last variable stops working, so if you use it you should figure out another way to solve your problem.

Finally, instead of writing a custom twig tag, I just created a Decorator for doctrines iterator to handle the extra stuff that I need, the only still broken is the loop.last var:

```
class DoctrineIterator implements \Iterator {

    public function __construct(\Iterator $iterator, $em) {
        $this->iterator = $iterator;
        $this->em = $em;
    }

    function rewind() {
        return $this->iterator->rewind();
    }

    function current() {
        $res = $this->iterator->current();
            //remove annoying array wrapping the object
        if(isset($res[0])) 
            return $res[0];
        else
            return null;
    }

    function key() {
        return $this->iterator->key();
    }

    function next() {
            //detach previous entity if present
        $res = $this->current();
        if(isset($res)) {
            $this->em->detach($res);
        }
        $this->iterator->next();
    }

    function valid() {
        return $this->iterator->valid();
    }
}
```